# Trouble Connecting to PostgreSQL Running in a Ubuntu VM

Tags: django, postgresql, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I have created an instance of PostgreSQL running in a Ubuntu/Bionic box in Vagrant/VirtualBox that will be used by Django in my dev environment. I wanted to test my ability to connect to it with either the terminal or pgAdmin before connecting with DJango, just to be sure it was working on that end first; the idea being that I could make later Django debugging easier if I am assured the connection works; but, I've had no success.

I have tried editing the configuration files that many posts suggest, with no effect. I can, however, ping the box via the ip assigned in  the Vagrantfile with no issue - but not when specifying port 5432 with `ping 10.1.1.1:5432`. I can also use psql from within the box, so it's running.

I have made sure to enable `ufw` on the vm, created a rule to allow port 5432 and insured that it took using `sudo ufw status`. I have also confirmed that I'm editing the correct files using the `show` command within `psql`.

Here are the relevant configs as they currently are:

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.hostname = "hg-site-db"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|

    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 1
  end

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", host_ip: "127.0.0.1", guest: 5432, host: 5432

   config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "10.1.1.1"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    # Update and upgrade the server packages.
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get -y upgrade

    # Install PostgreSQL
    sudo apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib   

    # Set Ubuntu Language
    sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8



  SHELL

end
```

/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf - I am aware this is insecure, but I was just trying to find out why it was not working, with plans to go back and correct this:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

Comment: You cannot ping a port. Ping doesn't use TCP and has no use for ports. If you want to check connectivity on a specific port you can use some other tool like nc or something.

Comment: @Mad Wombat - good to know. I'm totally out of my element with this networking stuff....i"d like to get back to Django now, haha.

Comment: Just try to use psql from outside to connect to the database. psql has flags that allow you to specify host and user. If you get something like timeout or connection refused, you have a network problem. If you get something like "database doesn't exist" or authentication error you have a database config problem

Comment: @Mad Wombat - I've tried that and it's connection refused, which is why I've tried all of the networking-related things above. Now, I need the council of wiser people, so here I am.

Comment: what if you remove the host_ip part of your forwarded port definition and only leave guest and host port?

Comment: @Mad Wombat - you are wise indeed...that did it! Please put that in the form of an answer so I can upvote and accept. Maybe add that Vagrant will give a list of interfaces to bridge to when booting up, and you must select whichever one is your ethernet port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in comments, you should remove host_ip from your forwarded port definition and just leave the guest and host ports.

Comment: And you were correct, sir! I am incredibly relieved right now, thanks again!